# Web API C# - Role based access

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, roles

I have a web app with three different user roles Admin, Reseller and Seller. Each seller is connected to a Reseller.

Lets say that we want to display a list of sellers, when the reseller makes a request to the API: 
GET: api/v1/members/sellers

The expected result would be all the sellers connected to that reseller. The controller could looks something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[MemberAuthorize(AllowGroup = "Admin,Reseller")]
[Route("sellers")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetSellers()
{
    var member = _memberHelper.GetCurrentMember();
    if (member.Role == "Reseller")
        return sellersByReseller;
    if (member.Role == "Admin")
        return getAllSellers;

    ...
}
```

This would work but in my eyes it does not look pretty, and hard to test.

Is there another approach with the C# Web API that you could use for this? Something similar to this would be really neat:

```
[HttpGet]
[MemberAuthorize(AllowGroup = "Reseller")]
[Route("sellers")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetSellers()
{
    getSellersByReseller;
}

[HttpGet]
[MemberAuthorize(AllowGroup = "Admin")]
[RoutePrefix("sellers")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetSellersAsAdmin()
{
    getAllSellers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to split it up like that, mainly because role-based authentication is not mutually exclusive. I.e. there should be nothing preventing a user from having both the "Admin" role and the "Reseller" role. How would the routing behave in that case? I.e. which controller action should then be called?

---

What I would suggest anyway is for you to split it up into two separate routes pretty much like you've already suggested:

```
[HttpGet]
[MemberAuthorize(AllowGroup = "Reseller")]
[Route("reseller/sellers")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetSellersByReseller()
{
    return getSellersByReseller;
}

[HttpGet]
[MemberAuthorize(AllowGroup = "Admin")]
[RoutePrefix("admin/sellers")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetAllSellers()
{
    return getAllSellers;
}
```

Whether the naming of the routes makes sense is for you to choose. The bottom line is that I would suggest avoiding having one route return different results. Yes, they both return a list of sellers but the premise is different and not just defined by e.g. a search term which would be acceptable for one route. Now, the two routes clearly are meant for two different things/audiences.